# neo4j cypher deep first search

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree-like graph as shown below [image]

Now let's say I start from the root node **R** and want to find all the **paths** from **1** to the nearest type **B** node. In the example graph, the result should be

```
path-1: 1,2
path-2: 1,3,6,10,13
path-3: 1,3,7,10,13
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the node type in the label - `(:A)` and `(:B)`, relationships between nodes are of type 'connect'.

```
// Find all paths from Root to all B-nodes
MATCH (A:A {name:1}), p = (A)-[:connect*]->(B:B)

  // Get all node labels for each path
  WITH A, p, extract( n in nodes(p) | labels(n) ) as pathLabels

  // We find the number of occurrences of B-node in each path
  WITH A, p, reduce( bCount = 0, Labels in pathLabels | 
                     CASE WHEN 'B' IN Labels THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + bCount
             ) as bCount

  // Return only the path in which the B-node is in the end of the path
  WHERE bCount = 1
RETURN p
```

Example data query:

```
MERGE (A1:A {name:1})-[:connect]-(B2:B {name:2}) MERGE (A1)-[:connect]-(A3:A {name:3}) MERGE (B2)-[:connect]-(A4:A {name:4}) MERGE (B2)-[:connect]-(A5:A {name:5}) MERGE (A4)-[:connect]-(B8:B {name:8}) MERGE (B8)-[:connect]-(A11:A {name:11}) MERGE (B8)-[:connect]-(A12:A {name:12}) MERGE (A5)-[:connect]-(A9:A {name:9}) MERGE (A3)-[:connect]-(A6:A {name:6}) MERGE (A3)-[:connect]-(A7:A {name:7}) MERGE (A6)-[:connect]-(A10:A {name:10}) MERGE (A7)-[:connect]-(A10) MERGE (A10)-[:connect]-(B13:B {name:13}) RETURN *
```

Update (searching not `A-type` nodes):

```
// Find all paths from Root to all not A-nodes 
MATCH (A:A {name:1}), p = (A)-[:connect*]->(B) WHERE NOT 'A' IN labels(B)

  // Get all node labels for each path
  WITH A, p, extract( n in nodes(p) | labels(n) ) as pathLabels

  // We find the number of occurrences of A-node in each path
  WITH A, p, reduce( aCount = 0, Labels in pathLabels | 
                     CASE WHEN 'A' IN Labels THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + aCount
             ) as aCount

  // Return only the path in which the count of A-node 
  // is 1 less the total number of nodes in the path.
  WHERE aCount = length(p)
RETURN p
```

Comment: It works. Just one quick question, how can I change from searching `type B nodes` to searching `NOT type A nodes`?

Comment: @StevenLuo If you are satisfied with the answer - do not forget to accept it [ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ]